# How to validate a large value set within HAPI-FHIR framework

Tags: validation, hapi, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I have a custom implementation of `org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.hapi.validation.IValidationSupport` module for validating all my profiles and value sets/code systems. I am trying to figure out a way to use the same validation API to support validation of very large value set.

Currently the default implementation of validating a value set/code system within HAPI-FHIR relies on expanding the whole value set and matching the submitted code against any of the concepts within the expanded value set. Is there a way to do the validation without the need of fully expanding the value set?

Answer (score 1):

Does your ValueSet include a large subset of a code system? There isn't currently a way in HAPI FHIR's validation framework to implement a method asking "does this ValueSet include a specific code".. Although I'd agree that would be useful.

Please feel free to file a bug or a pull request.

Comment: Sorry for a horrendously late reply. Yes the ValueSet contains the Health Canada Drug Product Database code system which amounts to about 60k+ entries. I've already started on making modifications to internal workings of HAPI-FHIR to allow for validating a single code within a code system and will file a pull request once it's ready. :)